# back up and restore mysql database c#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database-backups, database-restore

I am looking for a way how I can via c# back up some database from mysql (file backup).
And also via c# restore database from backup file to some new location.

Can you help me with some ideas how to get started here .

Thanks.

Comment: Basically you'd want to replicate mysqldump from within C#, at which point you'd be better off just invoking mysqldump.

Comment: I have found now this one I think it will do the job for me

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ConnectCsharpToMysql.aspx

Comment: @MarcB Some ASP.NET web hosting prevent the use of MySqlDump to be executed on their server.

Answer (score 4):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
Process.Start(startInfo);
startInfo.Arguments = "mysqldump -u admin -p admin test > c:\backupfile.sql";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

You can hide the dos prompt with startInfo.WindowStyle if you need.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative to MySqlDump, you can try **MySqlBackup.NET**: https://github.com/MySqlBackupNET/MySqlBackup.Net

Example

**Backup/Export a MySQL Database**

```
string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";

// Important Additional Connection Options
constring += "charset=utf8;convertzerodatetime=true;";

string file = "C:\\backup.sql";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            mb.ExportToFile(file);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Import/Restore a MySQL Database**

```
string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";

// Important Additional Connection Options
constring += "charset=utf8;convertzerodatetime=true;";

string file = "C:\\backup.sql";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            mb.ImportFromFile(file);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The CodeProject you found does backups by calling mysqldump.exe and does restores by calling mysql.exe from within a C# program (as Marc B recommended).

**As an alternative, this CodeProject actually generates the SQL statements itself instead of calling an external program:**

- [Making Your Own MySQL Backup and Restore Tools in C# (Supports Unicode, UTF8)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256466/Making-Your-Own-MySQL-Backup-and-Restore-Tools-In)
- [CodePlex Repository](http://mysqlbackuprestore.codeplex.com/)

*(It's not as fast or reliable as using mysqldump.exe / mysql.exe, but you can learn a lot from it.)*

Comment: Hi, there is a new version (1.3) of the software(link) that you've provided. Whats your comment of that version?

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDump.html